# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature BinaryTree Type Script

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement binary search tree in Type Script using generic types. However I have an issue with adding child in node, because there is an error when parent.leftChild(newNode) - "Cannot invoke an expression whose type is lacks a call signature. Type Node has no compatible call signatures."

```
export { };

class  Node <T> {
    private _key: number;
    private _data: T;
    private _leftChild: Node <T>;
    private _rightChild: Node <T>;
    constructor(key: number, data: T) {
        this._key = key;
        this._data = data;
    }
    get key(): number {
        return this._key;
    }
    get data(): T {
        return this._data;
    }
    get leftChild(): Node <T> {
        return this._leftChild;
    }
    get rightChild(): Node <T> {
        return this._rightChild;
    }
    set leftChild(child: Node <T>) {
        this._leftChild = child;
    }
    set rightChild(child: Node <T>) {
        this._rightChild = child;
    }
}

class BinaryTree <H> {
    private _root: Node<H>;
    public addNode(key: number, data: H): void {
        const newNode: Node <H> = new Node <H> (key, data);
        if (this._root == null) {
            this._root = newNode;
        } else {
            let focusNode: Node <H> = this._root;
            let parent: Node <H>;
            while (true) {
                parent = focusNode;
                if (key < focusNode.key) {
                    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    if (focusNode == null) {
                        parent.leftChild(newNode);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `leftChild` is a property setter not a function so try `parent.leftChild = newNode` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors)

Comment: @peter-hull Thanks man! It works! I've tried to fix it for over 24 last hours)) Why TS has so weird syntax????)

Comment: Glad it works. As an aside, since your property accessors don't have any computation in them, you can just expose the bare properties (marking `data` and `key` as readonly)